# What is exactly eigenfunction in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

What is exactly eigenfunction in quantum mechanics i understand eigenvalue and eigenvectors but does it mean boundary condition in quantum mechanics

Comment: Have you checked Wikipedia ?

Comment: Watch some MIT open courseware videos. They explain it very nicely.

Comment: It is an eigenvector in a function space. In a Hilbert space like $L^2$ that is used in quantum mechanics, all vectors are functions and therefore eigenvector and eigenfunction can be used synonymously.

Comment: Not clear. Please explain your difficulty.

Comment: @Luke the Hilbert space is generally not as simple as $L^2$, being totally rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalue problem of a real operator $\hat{A}$ is technical but basic in quantum theory. It consists on finding every pair of real number $x$ and ket $|\alpha\rangle$ satisfying the eigenvalue equation:

\begin{equation}
\widehat{A}|\alpha \rangle = |\alpha\rangle x. 
\end{equation}

$|\alpha\rangle$ is the eigenket and $x$ is the eigenvalue.

If you have a generalized orthonormal basis $\langle\mathbf{x}|$ you can project your quantum eigenket and obtain your eigenfunction:

\begin{equation}
\langle\mathbf{x}|\alpha\rangle=\alpha(\mathbf{x}). 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different operators you could construct as an example to answer this question, but in order to try and ease into it I'm just going to use the concept of Energy.

Take an Energy Operator $\hat E$,  $$\hat E\psi = e\psi$$ Where $\psi$ is the quantum state and $e$ is the eigenvalue that [according to the basic postulates of Quantum Mechanics is a real value that corresponds to an observable] $\hat E$ generates.

This observable value isn't where the adventure ends though, as you take the Observable and you can use the Schrodinger equation, a second order differential equation, and use the Energy eigenvalue to help solve it. Consider the infinite potential well, The solution to this gives you the complex probability amplitude function which can be multiplied with its conjugate to give you a real function describing the probability of finding the particle at various points in the well. The energy eigenvalue corresponding to some pure Energy state now also corresponds to some eigenfunction solution to the differential equation, so you now have functions describing the probability of finding the particle dependent on the Energy state it's in.

I'll go through the 1-D potential well now in case it's unclear:

Let $V(x)$ correspond to the potential energy, and let it be fully defined by,
$$V\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}0 & 0<x<L \\ \infty &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
That is, in between $0$ and $L$ [the edges of the potential 'box'] the potential energy is $0$, and outside of or at those boundaries the potential is infinite. This means that you would not find the particle in those areas of infinite potential as that would require infinite energy to get it there in the first place, so now we have some boundary conditions.

The Schrodinger equation is of the form: $$\hat H \psi = (\hat T + \hat V)\psi$$ $\hat T$ can be derived fairly easily from the solution to the wave equation, $Ae^{i(kx-wt)}$ just by differentiating and transposing, giving $$\hat T = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\psi(x)$$ $\hat H$ isn't that important, since we're only concerned about the Eigenvalues of it, which we can already obtain now since we have $\hat T$, $\hat V$ and assuming that $\psi$ is of the form $A\cos(kx) + B\sin(kx)$. Since there is no chance of finding the particle at $0$ or $L$, we can drop the $A\cos(kx)$ term.

Plugging our assumed form of $\psi$ into the equation, dropping out the V term as it doesn't exist in between $0$ and $L$ which is accounted for by boundary conditions $\psi(0) = 0$ and $\psi(L) = 0$ and equating it to $\hat H \psi = e\psi$ we get: $$e = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$$ which we can rearrange to obtain $k = \frac{\sqrt{2me}}{\hbar}$. We can now substitute that into $\psi(x)$, obtaining: $$B\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2me}}{\hbar}x\right)$$ The corresponding eigenfunction. If you wanted to, you could then go on further, derive a relation between $k$ and the $e$th eigenvalue,and evaluate the integral using the fact that the integral of the square of the function from $0$ to $L$ must equal $1$ to find the value of $B$.